I'm getting "Invalid argument(s)" error when using TensorFlow Lite model in my Flutter app
I'm developing a mobile app using Flutter and I'm trying to use a model trained with TensorFlow Lite in my app. However, I get "ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s))" error when running the model. I use the following code to load the model and process the input data:
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
......
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
.....
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? classifications;

 ...
  }

  Future<void> loadModelAndRun() async {
    final interpreter = await loadModel();

    
    final inputImage = await loadImage('assets/e2.jpeg');

   
    final output = await runModel(interpreter, inputImage);

    setState(() {
      classifications = output;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sınıflandırma Sonuçları'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Top 3 Predictions:",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (classifications != null)
              Column(
                children: classifications!.map((prediction) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(prediction['className']),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "Confidence: ${prediction['confidence'].toStringAsFixed(2)}%",
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Interpreter> loadModel() async {
    final modelData = await rootBundle.load('assets/inceptionv3_model.tflite');
    final Uint8List modelBytes = modelData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return Interpreter.fromBuffer(modelBytes);
  }

  Future<Uint8List> loadImage(String imagePath) async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    return data.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> runModel(
    Interpreter interpreter,
    Uint8List inputImage,
  ) async {
    interpreter.allocateTensors();

    // Giriş tensorunu al
    final inputs = interpreter.getInputTensors();
    final inputShape = inputs[0].shape;
    print("Model Giriş Tensor Boyutu: $inputShape");

 
    final img = imglib.decodeImage(inputImage)!;
    final resizedImage = imglib.copyResize(img, width: 299, height: 299);
    final imgBytes = resizedImage.getBytes();
    final imgArray = Float32List.fromList(imgBytes.map((e) => e / 255.0).toList());
    final inputImageData = imgArray.buffer.asUint8List();

   
    inputs[0].data = inputImageData; //ı get error this line

    
    interpreter.invoke();

    
    final outputs = interpreter.getOutputTensors();
    final outputData = outputs[0].data.buffer.asFloat32List();

   
    final classIndices = {
      0: "anıtkabir", 1: "apollon", 2: "aspendos", 3:"ayasofya", 4:"eyfel", 5: "galata", 6: "katedral", 7:"kolezyum", 8:"pisa", 9:"selimiye"
    };

    final topClasses = outputData
        .asMap()
        .entries
        .map((entry) => {'classIndex': entry.key, 'score': entry.value})
        .toList();

    topClasses.sort((a, b) => b['score']!.compareTo(a['score']!));

    final top3Predictions = topClasses.take(3).map((entry) {
      final classIndex = entry['classIndex'];
      final className = classIndices[classIndex];
      final confidence = entry['score']! * 100;
      return {'className': className, 'confidence': confidence};
    }).toList();

    return top3Predictions;
  }
}

Here are some details about my implementation:
I load the TensorFlow Lite model using the loadModel function, which loads the model from an asset file (inceptionv3_model.tflite).
The input image data is loaded using the loadImage function, which loads the image from an asset file (e2.jpeg).
I resize the input image to match the expected input size of the model (299x299 pixels).
I convert the resized image data to a Uint8List and normalize the pixel values to the range [0, 1].
Despite these preparations, I still encounter the "ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s))" error when trying to assign the input data to the input tensor of the model.
Could you please help me understand what might be causing this error? Are there any additional steps or considerations I should take when assigning input data to a TensorFlow Lite model in Flutter?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Hi @hilmi, You error shows that the shape of the input tensor is not match the expect shape, the model you are using inceptionV3, which expect input shape (1,299,299,3) for images and also check that you are putting correct  data type ,Please check if you are still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
